# Need to find a file with size more than 1GB with extension of file type

Tags: linux, find

I need to find a file with size more than 1GB with extension of file should be either tar or gzip or zip

I used below command to find

`find /home/test -type f -size +1G -and -regex '\(.*tar\|.*gzip\|.*zip\|.*tgz\)'`

But when i am combining file size with the file extension above command is not working.

Please let me know how to find the file which is having size more than 1 GB and the extension of the file should tar or gzip or zip

Comment: Should work from what you have written. Can you post a sample of the output from the size and regex parameters run separately?

Comment: When I ran that command no output on the screen

Comment: Are you sure you have files over 1G in size? Are you sure you have files with the extensions required?

Comment: 1.0G    flex.tar
50M     gopi.tgz
1.0G    net.zip
2.0G    sap
1.0G    test.img

Above files are present in the folder where i am searching

Comment: If they are 1GB in size, +1G won't return them as you are asking find to search for files greater than 1G

Comment: Please provide the command to find greater that equal to 1 GB

Comment: +999M. If you need more accuracy, use bytes or kilobytes.

Comment: Thanks a lots after changing 1G to +999M command working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are searching for files OVER 1GB in size which will exclude any files equalling 1GB in size

```
find /home/test -type f -size +1G -and -regex '\(.*tar\|.*gzip\|.*zip\|.*tgz\)'
```

To attain files that are equal to 1GB and above, use something like:

```
find /home/test -type f -size +999M -and -regex '\(.*tar\|.*gzip\|.*zip\|.*tgz\)'
```

If you need more accuracy, use c for bytes or k for kilobytes when specifying size.